# How to set the width of a DropDown in an Aspx page in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, styling, html-select

Hi all how can i set the the width or style the DropDown in my aspx page in MVC3

```
    i am using this statement

       <%:Html.DropDownList("Projects")%>
```

Comment: Just to be specific, you can write the html attributes as shown by @Iridio , and for your case, you can write  <%:Html.DropDownList("Projects", new { width="100px" })%> 
PS: While applying the stylesheet/class you should escape it with '@', like '@class'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470380.aspx). 
You can use this statement for inline style

```
<%:Html.DropDownList("Projects", Model.ProjectsList, new { @class="myCssClass" })%>
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I forgot the SelectList param (as stated in the link I posted). Updated assuming you're using a ViewModel